# Zend 2 changing database design

Tags: php, zend-framework, database-design, zend-framework2, agile

We are planning to develop a web app (front-end + back-end + business logic + model) for a client using the Zend 2 framework.

One of our developers fears and claims (arguably) that the database tables design has to be done once and for all at the beginning of the project, that we should not tolerate any future fields or entities to be added to the design in the future.

Coming from an Agile (non-web) world, I am not really confortable with this claim and if required we would simply leave Zend for another framework. Allowing the client to add new features in the future to the tables diagram is essential to our project.

Do you have any clues, ideas, documentation (official), that could support the hypothesis that Zend 2 is fit for evolutive design? And possible something less abstract than this: http://martinfowler.com/articles/evodb.html

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I would certainly like to hear how exactly does ZF inhibit changes into a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact Zend is just a framework/library wich provides some functionality to your application. You simply don't have to use the Zend components for database interaction if it will restrict you in any way.

For example you could simply add a layer between database and Zend which supports all the stuff you want to do. I know that Zend 2 works great with a ORM/ODM framework (like Doctrine).

Most of theese frameworks will provide you the functionality for simple database scheme migration, so there is almost no migration effort at all (if you just add a field or something).

Answer (score 0):

No framework will stop you from making your project evolve… and I don't know any project whose database never changed! Agile is "collaborate and keep improving". It's the same in an agile world web. It seems your developer is not comfortable with Zend Framework or maybe had a bad experience with it… time to ask him to share with you about that ;-)